# Converting MS ACCESS query into SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, porting

I have the following access query which I need to run in mssql:

```
SELECT
    [PUB_op-mstr].[om-job], 
    Last([PUB_op-mstr].[om-emp]) AS [LastOfom-emp], 
    Max([PUB_op-mstr].[om-dt-end]) AS [MaxOfom-dt-end], 
    [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr]

FROM
    PUB_wc_mstr INNER JOIN [PUB_op-mstr]
    ON
    PUB_wc_mstr.wc_wkctr = [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr]
GROUP BY 
    [PUB_op-mstr].[om-job],
    [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr], 
    PUB_wc_mstr.wc_dept 
HAVING
    (((Max([PUB_op-mstr].[om-dt-end]))>=Date()-7 
    And 
    (Max([PUB_op-mstr].[om-dt-end]))<Date()) 
    AND ((PUB_wc_mstr.wc_dept)="633" Or (PUB_wc_mstr.wc_dept)="646"));
```

Answer (score 1):

MS SQL doesn't support `LAST` aggregate function. So, you can just replace it with Min / Max. Or you have write your own `SELECT` like

```
[LastOfom-emp] = (SELECT ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`LAST()` in Access gives the last element of the column you're looking in. 
Example: `T1` has one column `c1`, which contains:

```
one
two
three
```

The statement:

```
SELECT LAST(c1) FROM T1
```

gives: three

Porting this function to SQL Server is doable, but only if there is (at least) one sorted column in the table. To get the last element of the column, you would have to do:

```
SELECT TOP(1) c1 FROM T1 ORDER BY c1 DESC;
```

This would give you the wrong result, namely "two" (because the column isn't sorted). So, to find in this case the right answer, you would need another column, for example an incrementing ID

```
c1     c2
one    1
two    2
three  3
```

Now you can:

```
SELECT TOP(1) c1 FROM T1 ORDER BY c2 DESC;
```

Since c2 is sorted, you now get the result "three".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Last([PUB_op-mstr].[om-emp])` is the `om-emp` value for the maximum `om-dt-end`, try:

```
select [om-job], [LastOfom-emp], [MaxOfom-dt-end], [om-wkctr] from
(SELECT [PUB_op-mstr].[om-job], 
        [PUB_op-mstr].[om-emp] AS [LastOfom-emp], 
        [PUB_op-mstr].[om-dt-end] AS [MaxOfom-dt-end], 
        [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr],
        row_number() over (partition by [PUB_op-mstr].[om-job], 
                                        [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr], 
                                        PUB_wc_mstr.wc_dept
                           order by [PUB_op-mstr].[om-dt-end] desc) rn
 FROM PUB_wc_mstr
 JOIN [PUB_op-mstr]
   ON PUB_wc_mstr.wc_wkctr = [PUB_op-mstr].[om-wkctr]
 WHERE PUB_wc_mstr.wc_dept IN ('633','646')
) sq
where rn=1 and 
      [MaxOfom-dt-end]>=Dateadd(d,-7, getdate()) And 
      [MaxOfom-dt-end]< getdate()
```